# Disabled button in cypress

Tags: automation, cypress

I would like to click on a button but in code it is showing as
"**button aria-disabled=:false**". How to change this in "true" and click the link using cypress?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Generally, it's the `disabled` attribute not the `aria-disabled` attribute that prevents Cypress from clicking. Even so, you should identify the button by `aria-label`

```js
cy.get('[aria-label="Expand Row"]').eq(0).click({force:true})`
```

There is a problem in the app, the `data-test-id` has `undefined` on the end which probably means the code that adds that attribute has a bug.

You would expect it to be something unique like `data-testid="expander-button-1"`.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply be able to use `.click()` after the finding the element. `aria-disabled=false` would imply that the button is enabled (not disabled).

```js
cy.get('[data-testid="expander-button-undefined"]').eq(0)
  .click();
```

If that is not working, it may be inheriting a disabled state from the class, role, or type. Without seeing where exactly it would be disabled, I can't recommend a strategy other than [using `force: true`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/click#Options).

```js
cy.get('[data-testid="expander-button-undefined"]').eq(0)
  .click({ force: true });
```

Comment: There are 10 elements found when I used "click{force:ture}. This command is selecting all 10 elements and I am getting the following error:
click{force: true}
CypressError
cy.click() can only be called on a single element. Your subject contained 10 elements. Pass { multiple: true } if you want to serially click each element. Any suggestion how to click on first link?

Comment: That happens when `cy.get()` returns multiple elements. With the HTML given (as well as the screenshot), it wouldn't be possible to know that the `cy.get()` command given would return multiple. Can you provide more HTML to assist with that?

Answer (score 0):

I used ":first-child" and then click on button.
cy.get('#row-0:first-child').click() and it works. Thank you all for your help.